# Using CloseableHttpClient with try-with-resources

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, try-with-resources

I've been searching for a completed example of `CloseableHttpClient` with try-with-resources. I am confused on if closing `CloseableHttpClient` also closes the `CloseableHttpResponse` object that will be created when I call `httpclient.execute(post)`. Do I need to wrap `CloseableHttpResponse` in a try-with-resources too?

Example:

```
try(CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().build()) {
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
    CloseableHttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(post);

    // do something with res
} catch (Throwable e) {
    // do something with error
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want for the reponse to take part in the try-with-resource you do. Although as you catch the Exceptions already, you can end with } - no additional catch required.

<s>**Technically** it's not a requirement as the implementation for `close ()` in CloseableHttpResponse [is empty](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b27/java/io/Closeable.java#Closeable.close%28%29)</s>

You need to close CloseableHttpResponse to release the resources, as per httpcomponents documentation (https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/quickstart.html)

Oh. **Don't catch Throwable** - this is bad style and can cause really hard to find errors.

Comment: Thanks, for the Throwable tip. It was like that in the code base, and I didn't know any better! I will change that.

Comment: @Jan Do you have any reference for this requirement?

Comment: I wish I could  give more upvotes for 'Don't catch Throwable'.

Comment: @oleg and Jan is there any good reason to use `Throwable` at all or just flat out never use it?

Comment: Your link to the "empty" close method in CloseableHttpResponse is broken, but CloseableHttpResponse is an *interface*, so it won't have implementation of the close() method.  It *is* a requirement that you run the close method because any CloseableHttpResponse implementation *should* have implemented the close() method properly.